# How to analyze Level 2 outcome variable when Level 1 parameters of the same person are drastically different

Tags: mathematical-statistics, least-squares, multilevel-analysis

I have a dataset with eye measurements (retinal thicknesses) of 250 participants (500 eyes). This data is cross sectional.

I am trying to build a model where the eye measurements can predict the brain volume of a participant. The eye measurements are a level 1 predictor (2 measurements per person), and the brain volume are a level 2 outcome (one per person).

The [recommended analysis](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-018-1025-8) is to average out the eye measurements, aggregating them to a level 2 variable (one averaged eye measurement per person). However, I expect the eyes on one person to vary dramatically in measurement because of history of inflammation (Right eye may be much thicker/inflammed than left eye).

How do I account for this in the model? Would I need to build a multi-level model? Unsure how to do so if it is a level 2 outcome and I get convergence issues with multilevel models.

| ID | Eye | EyeThickness | BrainVolume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | L | 134 | 45 |
| 001 | R | 456 | 45 |
| 002 | L | 102 | 56 |
| 002 | R | 521 | 56 |
| 003 | L | 453 | 49 |
| 003 | R | 162 | 49 |

Brain Volume, being a level 2 outcome, has the same value per row of Eye thickness, so that even if I tell the model to convey a random slope by ID, I get convergence issues.

I am using R. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to incorporate an eye-level variable (inflamation in a particular eye), then either you can average the inflamation variable for both eyes and proceed with a similar model, or you can use a mixed effects / multilevel model with a level-2 outcome (and person-level covariates), and level 1 covariates (eye inflamation).

Comment: Thank you for your response, Robert. I tried that with `lmerTest` but I kept running into convergence issues, which makes sense because both level 1 rows have the same level 2 measurement. I edited my question to contain an example of my data structure.

Comment: What is the syntax of your model please ?